# Turning a riemann sum into a definite intergral

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have this specific riemann sum, and I can't find a way to turn it into a definite integral.

I understand this is considered to be pretty basic. Does anyone mind explaining the way of solution for me? Thanks!

The integral:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \space {1 \over n^2 }\sum_{k=1}^n \space k\sin\left({\pi k\over n} \right)$$

Comment: You might want also to have a look at https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-accumulation-riemann-sums/ab-defining-definite-integral/a/definite-integral-as-the-limit-of-a-riemann-sum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionary is that $\frac kn$ corresponds to $x$ and $\frac1n$ corresponds to $\mathrm dx$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}
& \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 {n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k \sin \left( \frac {\pi k} n \right) \\
=& \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \color{red}{\frac 1 n} \sum_{k=1}^n \color{blue}{\frac kn} \sin \left( \frac {\pi \color{blue}k} {\color{blue}n} \right) \\
=& \displaystyle \int_0^1 \color{blue}x \sin (\pi \color{blue}x) \ \color{red}{\mathrm dx} \\
=& \displaystyle \frac12 \int_0^1 x \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx + \frac12 \int_0^1 x \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx \\
=& \displaystyle \frac12 \int_0^1 x \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx + \frac12 \int_0^1 (1-x) \sin (\pi (1-x)) \ \mathrm dx \\
=& \displaystyle \frac12 \int_0^1 x \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx + \frac12 \int_0^1 (1-x) \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx \\
=& \displaystyle \frac12 \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \ \mathrm dx \\
=& \displaystyle \frac12 \left[ -\frac1\pi \cos(\pi x) \right]_0^1 \\
=& \dfrac1\pi
\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't get how that $ {1\over n} $ turn into $ dx $ I'm sorry, I'm a beginner to intergrals

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ is divided to $n$ equal parts, so $\Delta x=\frac1n$, and it will (formally) become the $dx$ part of the integral.

Comment: How did u turn the $ x \sin( \pi x ) $ into $(1-x) \sin( \pi (1 - x)) $ ?

Comment: @fdsaddsa it's the $a+b-x$ substitution, i.e. I substitute $x$ by $0+1-x$ (the lower limit and the upper limit)